# Regular expression for phrase contain literals and numbers but is not all phrase as a number only with fixed range length

Tags: java, regex

i want to have regular expression to check input character as `a-z` and `0-9` but i do not want to allow input as just numeric value at all ( must be have at least one alphabetic character)

for example :

`413123123123131`
not allowed but if have just only one alphabetic character in any place of phrase it's ok

i trying to define correct Regex for that and at final i raised to

`[0-9]*[a-z].*`
but in now i confused how to defined `{x,y}` length of phrase i want to have `{9,31}` but after last `*` i can not to have length block too i trying to define group but unlucky and not worked

tested at https://www.debuggex.com/

how can i to add it ??

Comment: Let's precise: do you allow *any* chars, or just alphanumeric ASCII chars?

Comment: Check this. https://regex101.com/r/LKITEz/1

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
^(?:(?=[a-z])[a-z0-9]{9,31}|(?=\d.*[a-z])[a-z0-9]{9,31})$
```

OR a bit shorter form:

```
^(?:(?=[a-z])|(?=\d.*[a-z]))[a-z0-9]{9,31}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LKITEz/2)

Explanation(for the 1st regex):

- `^` - position before the start of the string
- `(?=[a-z])[a-z0-9]{9,31}` means If the string starts with a letter, then match Letters and digits. minimum 9 and maximum 31
- `|` - OR
- `(?=\d.*[a-z])[a-z0-9]{9,31}` means If the string starts with a digit followed by a letter somewhere in the string, then match letters and digits. Minimum 9 and Maximum 31. This also ensures that If the string starts with a digit and if there is no letter anywhere in the string, there won't be any match
- `$` - position after the last literal of the string

OUTPUT:

```
413123123123131                                        NO MATCH(no alphabets)
kjkhsjkf989089054835werewrew65                         MATCH 
kdfgfd4374985794379857984379857weorjijuiower           NO MATCH(length more than 31)
9087erkjfg9080980984590p465467                         MATCH 
4131231231231a                                         MATCH
kjdfg34                                                NO MATCH(Length less than 9)
```

Comment: when you are sure to answer is correct just put it as a answer not a comment , Thanks bro

Answer (score 4):

What you seek is

```
String regex = "(?=.{9,31}$)\\p{Alnum}*\\p{Alpha}\\p{Alnum}*";
```

Use it with `String#matches()` / `Pattern#matches()` method to require a full string match:

```
if (s.matches(regex)) {
    return true;
}
```

**Details**

- `^` - implicit in `matches()` - matches the start of string
- `(?=.{9,31}$)` - a positive lookahead that requires 9 to 31 any chars other than line break chars from the start to end of the string
- `\\p{Alnum}*` - 0 or more alphanumeric chars
- `\\p{Alpha}` - an ASCII letter
- `\\p{Alnum}*` - 0 or more alphanumeric chars

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/9Zkf0J):

```
String lines[]  = {"413123123123131", "4131231231231a"};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=.{9,31}$)\\p{Alnum}*\\p{Alpha}\\p{Alnum}*");
for(String line : lines)
{
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(line + ": MATCH");
    } else {
        System.out.println(line + ": NO MATCH");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
413123123123131: NO MATCH
4131231231231a: MATCH
```

Comment: Thanks , but  i check accept to kira's answer because their answer  worked as old conditions and he answered earlier as a comment i think it's fair , i up vote by one as your answer is correct too and worked

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you are looking for.

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*
```

To help explain it, think of the middle term as your one required character and the outer terms as any number of alpha numeric characters.

Edit: to restrict the length of the string as a whole you may have to check that manually after matching. ie.

```
if (str.length > 9 && str.length < 31)
```

Wiktor does provide a solution that involves more regex, please look at his for a better regex pattern

Comment: Note that `\w` matches a digit or letter or `_`. The regex you have matches all digits, too. Also, `[\w\d]` = `\w`, thus, your regex is the same as `\w*\w\w*`.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew! That's right, I'll edit it.

Comment: It looks good now. BTW, it is also possible to check the string length with a positive lookahead. [See my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45768992/3832970).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but until i detailed problem is i want to do all by regex not two part controlling . could you to define {x,y} in your regext phrase ?

Comment: @javaacm See my answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew's Answer has the better regex solution give his a look and a +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex:

```
[a-zA-Z\d]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*
```

The trick here is to have something that is *not* optional. The leading and trailing `[a-zA-Z\d]` has a `*` quantifier, so they are optional. But the `[a-zA-Z]` in the middle there is not optional. The string must have a character that matches `[a-zA-Z]` in order to be matched.

However, you need to check the length of the string with `length` afterwards and not with regex. I can't think of any way how you can do this in regex.

Actually, I think you can do this regexless pretty easily:

```
private static boolean matches(String input) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i))) {
            return input.length() >= 9 && input.length() <= 31;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```